# Появилась ошибка при переходе на php7

Tags: mysql, mysqli, php7

Наконец установил php7
До этого все отлично работало на php5.6, даже без замены mysql на mysqli
Но установил php7 - сайт вывалился в ошибки, все вызовы работы с базой я быстро переписал, но появилась непонятная ошибка...

```
php fatal error uncaught error using $this when not in object context
```

Я приведу код где она вызывается, хотя на других участках работа с базой как то же идет. и доходит именно до этого места и тут ему что то не нравится...

```
class Site extends Widget
{

    function Site(&$parent)
    {

        Widget::Widget($parent);
        $this->main = new Widget($this);
        $this->categories = Storefront::get_categories();
        ...
    }
...
}

class Storefront extends Widget
{
  function Storefront(&$parent)
  {
  Widget::Widget($parent); // там появляется указатель на db
  // this->db = &parent->db, так как база инициализируеться в widget
  ...
  }

  // Функция возвращает категории товаров, и их подкатегории
  function get_categories($parent = 0)
  {   
    $r = $this->db->query($query);  // * вот на этой строчке

    $tree = array();

    while ($category = $this->db->fetchObject($r)) {

        // .... тут я работаю с категориями,
```

щас приведу код этой функции query

```
# Execute the query or queries array
public function query($q)
{
    if ($this->link) {
        $start = microtime(true);
        $this->res_id = mysqli_query($this->link,$q);
    }
    else {
        $this->error_msg = "Could not execute query to $this->db_name database, wrong database link";
        return 0;
    }
    if (!$this->res_id && $this->exception_on_error) {
        trigger_error("Could not execute query to $this->db_name database, wrong result id", E_USER_ERROR);
        return 0;
    }
    return $this->res_id;
}
```

у меня вызывается так:
Site наследник widget (в нем прописаны инициализации класса бд)
В site вызывается конструктор widget (там подкл к бд) в классе widget есть this->db = new db.class  в нем все функции по работе c базой.
Когда мы используем db в site, то там прописывается this->db= & parent->db;
и к базе обращаюсь уже через this-db...
В site вызываем еще один класс, отвечающий за вывод категорий store, он тоже наследник widget..
Надеюсь понятно)

Comment: А вот та строчка у вас находится в методе одного из классов или вне любого класса?

Comment: щас дополню в вопросе

Comment: Лучше покажите код файла, в котором прописан `$r = $this->db->query($query);` ........Может вы там в статическом методе это делаете.....а также показать как вы этот самый метод вызываете..... может вы вызываете наоборот нестатический метод как статический. т.е. `foobar::foobarfunc();` а надо `foobar->foobarfunc();`

Comment: код то большой. я значит создаю новый класс как наследник главного и в конструкторе делаю там class Storefront extends Widget
{   
    function Storefront(&$parent)
    {
        Widget::Widget($parent); .......
Делаю это чтобы он унаследовал все параметры родителя через &

Comment: Мы же не знаем что у вас там в родителе прописано и вообще...... метод как объявлен? как статический или нет? А как вызывается?

Comment: я слово static вобще не использую. 
метод какой? query - я ж написал, public function

Comment: А на какой строке ошибка в функции query ?

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг причем тут `query`? метод, в котором написана строка `$r = $this->db->query($query);` нужен..... или где эта строка вообще находится? в шаблоне? или где в таком случае

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а, ну да, смотреть место вызова $this->db->query.

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос - смотрите, что надо еще добавлю.

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг еще вы не написали как вызывается `get_categories` ......то есть вот так через стрелку `->get_categories()` или так `::get_categories()`

Comment: Вот жеж, как знали куда копать. я добавил код где вызываю. А на что мне этот статик заменить? дело в том что я вызываю построение категорий без инициальзации класса. как можно заменить исправить? желательно оставив чтобы категории получались в том месте

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг вы вызываете Storefront::get_categories(), т.е. у вас не объекта Storefront. Следовательно вы не можете обращаться к нему по $this->

Comment: ок исправил. а не подскажите еще ругается на эту строчку
$site = new Site($a = null);  
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message PHP notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in ..."

Comment: Все исправил всем спасибо)